# How to pick video from my computer to flutter web app?

Tags: flutter

I want to pick video file from my computer and play it in flutter web app. I'm using `video_player` to play the video, but since flutter web does not support `dart:io`, I only can use `VideoPlayerController.asset()` and `VideoPlayerController.network()`. I cannot find how to play picked video file. Is there any way to play it?